# How to create next and back push buttons in Guide Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm making a GUI, and I'm using GUIDE for it. Before writing my question, I have to explain some details, so they are:
-Kind of data: text file, data from EMG of 16 muscles of 2 human's legs, so I have to plot 16 graphs.
-Objective of my GUI is to show 4 in each "page", so I need next and back push button to  be able to see all 16 graphs.In other words, my Gui needs 4 "pages".
-My GUIDE is made of 1 push bottom to browser my data, 1 push bottom to switch(update) the shape of 4 graphs showed to wave in ABS, graphs with envelope, and a combination of ABS & enveloped graphs, 1 popmenu to switch the shapes of the showed graphs, and two extra push bottom, one is next button and another one is back button.

To sum up, I'm just stuck in how to create the next and back button. The others roles of my code have been developed.

Thanks in advance.

Ps: Thanks for the person who suggested that I improve my question.

Yes, I want to redraw my graphs(My english is not so good, so I couldn't explain better)

->>>>>>> It is my Browser Function

```
    function Search_Patient_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to Search_Patient (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    % Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of Search_Patient
        global cell_data
        [file, path]=uigetfile('*.txt', 'Select file');
        arq = [path,file];
        full_pathname=strcat(path,file);
        text=fileread(full_pathname);
        cell_data= textscan(text, repmat('%f',1,41),'headerlines',11);

        delimiter = '\t';
        startRow = 3;
        endRow = 8;
        formatSpec = '%*s%*s%*s%f%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%[^\n\r]';
        fileID = fopen(arq,'r');
        textscan(fileID, '%[^\n\r]', startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
        dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow-startRow+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'ReturnOnError', false);

        time_foot1 = dataArray{:, 1};

    %h = handles.Search_Patient;
    %setappdata(0,'My_main_Data',cell_data)
                     setappdata(0,'time_foot',time_foot1)


    handles = guidata(hObject); %Updating variables
    guidata(hObject,handles);   %Updating variables
```

---

->>>>>>>It is my updating function.

```
    function Updating_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    % hObject    handle to Updating (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    global cell_data
    y_data=0.001;
    t=(cell_data{1,1})/1000;
    time_foot1= getappdata(0,'time_foot');
    text_rfoot=0.0009;
    text_lfoot=0.0007;


    [emg1_1 emg2_1 emg3_1 emg4_1  emg1e_1 emg2e_1 emg3e_1 emg4e_1]=emg_signal(cell_data); % EMG RMS and EMG Envelope



    popup_sel_index = get(handles.popupmenu, 'Value');
    switch popup_sel_index
        case 1        
            axes (handles.axes1);
            plot (t,emg1_1,'r-');
            title('EMG Left Vastus medialis  :  ' )
            xlabel('Time(s)')
            ylabel('Voltage (uV)')

             axes (handles.axes2);
             plot (t,emg2_1,'r-');

            axes (handles.axes3);
            plot (t,emg3_1,'r-');

            axes (handles.axes4);
            plot (t,emg4_1,'r-');

            axis ([t(1) (t(1)+(length (t')/1000)) 0 y_data])
            %Right-Foot Strike1
            text(time_foot1(4),text_rfoot, ' Right-Strike 1', 'Color', 'k')
            line('XData',[time_foot1(4) time_foot1(4)], 'YData', [0 y_data], 'LineStyle', '-','LineWidth', 1, 'Color','k');
            %Right  Foot Off
            text(time_foot1(6),text_rfoot, ' Right-Off', 'Color', 'k')
            line('XData',[time_foot1(6) time_foot1(6)], 'YData', [0 y_data], 'LineStyle', '-','LineWidth', 1, 'Color','k');
            %Right-Foot Strike2
            text(time_foot1(5),text_rfoot, ' Right-Strike 2', 'Color', 'k')
            line('XData',[time_foot1(5) time_foot1(5)], 'YData', [0 y_data], 'LineStyle', '-','LineWidth', 1, 'Color','k');
            %Left-Foot Strike
            text(time_foot1(1),text_lfoot, ' Left-Strike', 'Color', 'b')
            line('XData',[time_foot1(1) time_foot1(1)], 'YData', [0 y_data], 'LineStyle', '-','LineWidth', 1, 'Color','b');
            %Left   Foot Off
            text(time_foot1(3),text_lfoot, ' Left-Off', 'Color', 'b')
            line('XData',[time_foot1(3) time_foot1(3)], 'YData', [0 y_data], 'LineStyle', '-','LineWidth', 1, 'Color','b');
            title('EMG Left Vastus medialis  :  ' )
            xlabel('Time(s)')
            ylabel('Voltage (uV)')

        case 2      
            axes (handles.axes1);
            plot (t,emg1e_1,'b-','linewidth', 2);
            title('EMG Left Vastus medialis  :  ' )
            xlabel('Time(s)')
            ylabel('Voltage (uV)')

            axes (handles.axes2);
            plot (t,emg2e_1,'b-','linewidth', 2);

            axes (handles.axes3);
            plot (t,emg3e_1,'b-','linewidth', 2);

            axes (handles.axes4);
            plot (t,emg4e_1,'b-','linewidth', 2);

        case 3
            axes (handles.axes1); 
            plot (t,emg1_1,'r-');
            hold on
            plot (t,emg1e_1,'b-','linewidth', 2);
            hold off

            axes (handles.axes2);
            plot (t,emg2_1,'r-');
            hold on
            plot (t,emg2e_1,'b-','linewidth', 2);
            hold off

            axes (handles.axes3);
            plot (t,emg3_1,'r-');
            hold on
            plot (t,emg3e_1,'b-','linewidth', 2);
            hold off

            axes (handles.axes4);
            plot (t,emg4_1,'r-');
            hold on
            plot (t,emg4e_1,'b-','linewidth', 2);
            hold off
    end

    a=get(handles.next_pushbutton,'Value')

    handles = guidata(hObject) 
    guidata(hObject,handles);
```

---

->>>>>>>>>Popmenu function

```
    function popupmenu_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to popupmenu (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

    % Hint: popupmenu controls usually have a white background on Windows.
    %       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
    if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
        set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
    end

    set(hObject, 'String', {'EMG_abs','EMG_Envelope','EMG_abs + EMG_Envelope'})
```

set(hObject, 'String', {'EMG_abs','EMG_Envelope','EMG_abs + EMG_Envelope'})

---

All my code is here, and I don't know if what I have done is the best way to program in Matlab because it is my first GUI that I'm making, and I have a lot of doubts.

Thanks

Comment: Somebody down-voted your question, probably because it doesn't give enough details. Several questions come to my mind : Do you use GUIDE ? What do you need your buttons to do exactly ? Only change the 4 graphs ? What did you try (I have no idea why you tried the while loop) ? How is your data stored ?
Anyway I would create a variable (let's call it handles.index) and each back/next button pressed would modify its vale (1,2,3 or 4). Then a function would be run to actualize the graphs following handles.index's value.

Comment: I still think you don't need to have 4 "pages" on your GUI. It's more simple to simply redraw your graphs once you push one of these previous/next buttons. If you don't see what I mean, you'll have to add your code for graphs to your question so that we see how you display them.

Comment: Yes, I really want to redraw. Thanks. Ps. My English is not so good, so I could not express my doubt better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me correct your code to show you the little mistakes you made (I'm not very experienced but I think that can help you). I didn't try to understand the `textscan(...)` calls since I don't have one of your txt files.

```
function Search_Patient_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % global cell_data (I avoid global variables)
    [file, path]=uigetfile('*.txt', 'Select file');
    % arq = [path,file]; (it is the same as below, no ?)
    full_pathname=strcat(path,file);
    text=fileread(full_pathname);

    cell_data= textscan(text, repmat('%f',1,41),'headerlines',11);
    delimiter = '\t';
    startRow = 3;
    endRow = 8;
    formatSpec = '%*s%*s%*s%f%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%[^\n\r]';
    fileID = fopen(full_pathname,'r');
    textscan(fileID, '%[^\n\r]', startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
    dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow-startRow+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'ReturnOnError', false);
    time_foot1 = dataArray{:, 1};

    % Now store the relevant data in the handles structure :
    handles.timefoot=timefoot1;
    handles.cell_data=cell_data;
    guidata(hObject,handles);   % This line saves the current handles (so it saves the changes above)
    % handles = guidata(hObject); % This line replaces current handles with the one stored. Use it only in the beginning of a function that doesn't take handles as an input, or after a call to a function that affects handles.
```

Then

```
function Updating_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    y_data=0.001;
    t=(handles.cell_data{1,1})/1000; % else you can say 'cell_data=handles.cell_data;' and use 'cell_data' as you did
    %time_foot1= getappdata(0,'time_foot'); (let is use the handles structure instead of getappdata)
    time_foot1=handles.time_foot;
    text_rfoot=0.0009;
    text_lfoot=0.0007;

    [emg1_1 emg2_1 emg3_1 emg4_1  emg1e_1 emg2e_1 emg3e_1 emg4e_1]=emg_signal(handles.cell_data); % EMG RMS and EMG Envelope

    popup_sel_index = get(handles.popupmenu, 'Value');
    switch popup_sel_index
        [skipping a few lines]
    end

    % a=get(handles.next_pushbutton,'Value') (what for ??)

    % handles = guidata(hObject) (you do not want to erase the handles structure do you ?)
    guidata(hObject,handles); % OK but not neccesary because nothing changed in the handles structure in the function)
```

Now **what you want to do** is modifying your Updating function so that it takes into account the number of times you pushed previous/back. I think. So I would create a simple variable `handles.index=1` inside the GUI `OpeningFcn` (don't forget to save it with `guidata`) and every time you push one of the buttons you would modify its value (+1 or -1). Then inside the Updating function, `newIndex=mod(handles.index,4);` and the newIndex tells you which "plane" you have to show.

An alternate solution is to use another popupmenu with strings `{'1','2','3','4'}` for instance, and use it as you use it already.

Comment: Thanks a lot! When should I use a global variable? I'm using "time_foot1" because I have to show in the graphs when the patient's feet is either strike or off so that I can see whether EMG is okay or not. But the only way I found to do show that is copy the part of the code all the time. is there a way of setting information in the axes?

Comment: %Right-Foot Strike1
            text(time_foot1(4),text_rfoot, ' Right-Strike 1', 'Color', 'k')
            line('XData',[time_foot1(4) time_foot1(4)], 'YData', [0 y_data], 'LineStyle', '-','LineWidth', 1, 'Color','k');
            %Right  Foot Off
            text(time_foot1(6),text_rfoot, ' Right-Off', 'Color', 'k')
            line('XData',[time_foot1(6) time_foot1(6)], 'YData', [0 y_data], 'LineStyle', '-','LineWidth', 1, 'Color','k');

Comment: Well it seems you will have to draw the ``text`` and ``line`` every time you update the axes, but if you want your code to be clean, you should create a new function that updates everything for one axes so that you just have one line of code to copy each time. For instance `update_one_axes(handles,current_axes_handle,right_off_yes_or_no)`.
Have fun ! :)